# Why does this Python code give Runtime Error(NZEC)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already read the other questions and answers but couldn't implement any of the solutions to my code. I'm still clueless about the reason why this code gives a runtime error.

I'm trying to submit the code on CodeChef, yet it gives the Runtime Error(NZEC), although the code runs flawlessly on my console for some inputs. Here's my code:

```
def GetSquares(base):
    if not base or base < 4:
        return 0
    else:
        x = (base - 4) - (base % 2) + 1
        return x + GetSquares(base - 4)

num_test = int(input())

for test in range(num_test):
    base = int(input())
    print (int(GetSquares(base)))
```

Codechef's explanation for NZEC:

> NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code. For C users, this will be
>   generated if your main method does not have a return 0; statement.
>   Other languages like Java/C++ could generate this error if they throw
>   an exception.

The problem I'm trying to solve:

https://www.codechef.com/problems/TRISQ

Comment: If I had to guess, the int() conversion is failing because the input isn't a valid integer. Try printing it before doing anything, if you can - are you sure that you're not supposed to split it or something? My either guess is that you're experiencing a (heh) stack overflow

Comment: What inputs does the program run with? What inputs does the program NOT run with?

Comment: What is the  input when it crashes?

Answer (score 3):

The problem description says that the input is constrained to be < 10^4. That's 10,000! Your code will need to make 10,000/4 = 2500 recursive calls to GetSquares, that's a lot! In fact, it's so much that it's going to give you, fittingly, this error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

You're going to have to think of a better way to solve the problem that doesn't involve so much recursion! Because you're doing this coding challenge, I'm not going to give a solution in this answer as that would sort of defeat the purpose, but if you'd like some prodding towards an answer, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The question puts a constraint on the value of '**B**' which is 10000 at max, which means there are a lot of recursive calls and giving a runtime error. Try solving using iteration.